# The professor of a large calculus class randomly selected 6 students

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling

and asked the amount of time (in hours) they spend for his course per week. The data are given below.

10, 8, 9, 7, 11, 13

Estimate the standard error of the estimated mean time spent in a week for this course by the students who are taking this course.

Ok
my work:

I've found $\hat{\mu}=\bar{x}=\cfrac{29}{3}$

$\hat{\sigma}=s=2.16 $ approximately

so $\hat{\sigma_\hat{\mu}}=s_\hat{\mu}=\cfrac{\hat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n-1}}=\cfrac{2.16}{\sqrt{5}} = .966$ approximately

so final answer should be $.966$ hours

But the book's answer says that the answer is $0.882$ hours

You get this answer via $\cfrac{2.16}{\sqrt{6}} = .882$ approximately

But this makes no sense to me. This would be population standard deviation for $\bar{x}$ NOT sample standard error/deviation for $\bar{x}$. Am I mistaken? Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{n-1}$ in the denominator not just $\sqrt{n}$ because it's a sample? If not why? Can someone explain this to me so that I understand the concept?

Comment: In my point of view your answer is correct as the standard variation of sample data and population is different with one degree of freedom. The reason behind it is that the provided mean is calculated based on the sample data and not the population. Can you tell me the book to check it out?

Comment: Never mind sir, It turns out the formula is indeed $\cfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$  as 
$ \cfrac{\hat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}} =  \cfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}} $ listed as the reason why...  I believe I just have to make the substitution for population standard error subbing the population part with the sample part, (as to why it's still n in the denominator as opposed to n-1... i don't know. I would appreciate an answer if you know however)

Comment: Actually I think I know. It's because everyone in the sample (all the students) would have the same variance wouldn't they? (each student/each random variable would have the same variance so Variance($\bar{x}$) = $\cfrac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{n}$ would it not? so just take the square root to find what I found in the earlier comment. Am I mistaken? Also we already took the n-1 in the denominator into account when we calculated sample sd ($s$) so there's no need to do so again. I.E. the n-1 is automatically accounted when we plug $s$ into $\cfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ so that's why it's n and not n-1. yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why there is difference between the variance of the sample data whether the mean is known or not could be explained with the degree of freedom. Assume we have $N$ independent data from a dataset, if the mean is unknown, it should be estimated as
$$
\overline x = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N x_i
$$
the expectation of discrepancy between sample variance and population variance is
$$
E \{ \sigma^2 - s^2 \} = E\left \{  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\mu)^2 - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\overline x)^2 \right \} \\ 
= E\left \{  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left ( ( x_i^2 - 2x_i\mu+\mu^2) - (x_i^2 - 2x_i\overline x + \overline x^2) \right) \right \}\\
= E\left \{  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left (  \mu^2 - \overline x^2 +  2x_i(\overline x - \mu) \right) \right \} = E\left \{ \mu^2 - \overline x^2  +  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left (2x_i(\overline x - \mu) \right) \right \} = E\left \{ (\overline x - \mu)^2 \right \} = var(\overline x) = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}
$$
So the expected value of sample variance have the following relation with the actual variance,
$$
E \{ s^2 \} = \sigma^2 - \frac{\sigma^2}{N} = \frac {N-1}{N} \sigma^2
$$
However, if our population only consists of the given numbers, then actual mean and estimated one would be identical and thus, there will be no difference between $\sigma$ and $s$.

Comment: Thank You very much!